# Flutter version solving failed error on this particular app

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

So, I just downloaded this source code of an app online made on Flutter. I set everything up but as soon as I type "flutter run" into the terminal, I get this error.

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 1.9.1+hotfix.6.                              

Because flutter_provider_app depends on cached_network_image >=2.0.0-rc which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.10.15-pre.148 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in Vulfpeck-fritter_for_reddit-fb59922...             
pub get failed (1)
```

This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: flutter_provider_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.11.1+3
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.14+1
  provider: ^3.1.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.1
  meta: ^1.1.7
  html_unescape: ^1.0.1+3
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc
  flutter_html: ^0.11.0
  flutter_custom_tabs: ^0.6.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I tried several fixes online but none of them help.

I'd really appreciate the help as I'm a newbie to Flutter. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Currently, you need either the master or [dev channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) of the Flutter SDK for web support.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal run command

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First change your channel to **dev**
   `flutter channel dev`
2. Upgrade flutter
   `flutter upgrade`
3. Get package
   `flutter pub get`

> it will work

Comment: Where does the quote come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image#-installing-tab-) to version 1.1.3

```
dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^1.1.3
```

You can install packages from the command line:

```
$ flutter pub get
```

Github [issue](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/271)

Comment: Tried changing cached_network_image to version 1.1.3. However, now I'm getting a whole new set of errors. I cant send it in a comment, because too long.

Answer (score 0):

cached_network_image: ^1.1.3 this version works for me!